# Multiply two arrays where a settlement is defined and the other not

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to multiply two arrays, but I surgue the following problem:

1. I have to take an amount of a texbox in c # example: 1000.00, what I do is take that amount and put it in an array.
2. have an array defined with three digits, {3,2,1}
3. my question, as I multiply the arrangement one (textbox) for the array containing the three digits ?? I want to multiply digit by digit
4. And the array containing three digits can be repeated depending on the size of the first array, for example:

   ```
   1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

   x | x | x | x | x | x |

   3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1
   ```

   result:

   ```
   3 |0  |0  | 0 |0  |0  |
   ```
5. He used the following code, but do not have a favorable result:

   ```
   void Metodo2()
   {

       var cifrita = new List<string>();//
       var numbers = new List<int>(new int[] { 3, 2, 1 });
       string cadena = textBox1.Text;
       char[] xd = cadena.ToCharArray();//
       int i = 0;
       foreach (char VARIABLE in xd)
       {
           cifrita.Add(xd[i].ToString());

           i++;
       }
       var query = from x in cifrita
                   from y in numbers
                   select int.Parse(x) * y;

       int[] thirdArray = query.ToArray();
       StringBuilder concatenatedString = new StringBuilder();
       foreach (var cifra in thirdArray)
       {
           concatenatedString.Append(cifra).Append(" ");

       }
       string result = concatenatedString.ToString();
       richTextBox1.Text = result;
   }
   ```

Comment: What does _...  but do not have a favorable result_ mean?

Comment: Entry the amount of 100,000 in the textbox and throws me the following result: 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.                                                         Sorry, I'm new here and not let me insert a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what is this good for, but this code should do it.

```
string input = "100000"; //your textbox input
int[] digits = new int[] { 3, 2, 1 }; // the digits to repeat
int[] numberB = new int[input.Length]; // the number componsed of 3, 2, 1, ...

//numberB creation
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberB.Length; ++i)
{
    numberB[i] = digits[index];
    ++index;
    if (index >= 3)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
}

int[] numberA = input.ToCharArray().Select(a => int.Parse(a.ToString())).ToArray(); // the input "number"
//multiplication
int[] output = new int[input.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; ++i)
{
    output[i] = numberA[i] * numberB[i];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and not let me insert a screenshot of result

Comment: No problem. I hope that my answer will help.

Comment: yes, it was very effective, spend many hours Breaking down the head and the result is now correct.                                                                                                   I have a question, I give points to the correct comments, or anything that helps to you ??

Comment: You may check the answer with the green tick and mark it with it as "resolving the problem". I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it with minimum change in your code :

```
        void Metodo2()
        {
            var cifrita = new List<string>();
            var numbers = new List<int>(new int[] { 3, 2, 1 });
            var result = new List<int>();
            string cadena = richTextBox1.Text;
            char[] xd = cadena.ToCharArray();//
            int i = 0;
            foreach (char c in xd)
            {
                result.Add((int)Char.GetNumericValue(c) * numbers[i]);
                i = (++i) % numbers.Count; // iterating over smaller list
            }

            StringBuilder concatenatedString = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var cifra in result)
            {
                concatenatedString.Append(cifra).Append(" ");

            }
            richTextBox1.Text = concatenatedString.ToString();
        }
```

consider using `Char.GetNumericValue(c)` while getting the number of a character.
I'd be so happy if it helps.

Comment: Thank's, is correct, thank you. I have a question, I give points to the correct comments, or anything that helps to you ??

Comment: @RafaelSaavedra Your welcome my friend. But I didn't get your point in this comment.